# Sparse matrix without knowing size

Tags: c++, eigen

Does Eigen support element insertion into a sparse matrix if the size is not known?

I have a stream of data coming in, and I am attempting to store that sparsely, but I don't know the maximum value of the indices (row/column) of the data ahead of time (I can guess, but not guarantee).  Looking at Eigen's insert code, it has an assertion (1130, SparseMatrix.h) that the index that you wish to insert into is <=rows(), <=cols().

Do I really need to wait until I have all the data before I can start using Eigen's sparse matrix code? The design I would have to go for then would require me to wait for all the data, then scanto find the maximum index, which is not ideal for my application. I curently don't need the full matrix to start working - an limited one with the currently available data would be fine.

Please don't close this question unless you have an answer, the linked answer was for dense matrices, not sparse ones, which have different internal storage...

I'm also looking for information on the case where matrix size is not immediately available at **run-time**, rather than at compile time, and olny for sparse.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree with OP, the duplicates are about dense matrices.

Comment: Inserting into a `SparseMatrix` is generally inefficient for initialization, unless you do it in order and ideally with a correctly pre-allocated matrix. I would suggest to accumulate a triplet-list and use `setFromTriplets`

Comment: @chtz Well, I didn't look too close, but the good thing is, they clarified that better in their question now. THX for notifying. _@OP_ research efforts from your side could be a bit better documented / presented.

Comment: @OP You should indeed clarify your question, e.g., what does "start working [with the matrix]" mean? How often do you get new data (compared to the amount of work you do with it)? How bad would a too large matrix be (with only zeros in the last rows/columns)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation is still to store the values into a intermediate triplets container and build the sparse matrix at the end. If you don't want to read all the stream... then just read first nnn triplets until your desired condition and then use setFromTriplets() with the partial list of triplets.

But, if you still don't want to read the full matrix to start working, you can guess a size for your matrix and make it grow in case you read a value that can not be stored in your current size using [conservativeResize()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#a9dc538b2c1fe9027ba58f31ee83b2ff1).

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <iostream>
 
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> mat;
mat.resize(100,100); //Initial size guess. Could be 1, 10, 1000, etc...


fstream inputStream ("filename.txt", "r"):
while(inputStream)
{
    //Read position and value from stream
    unsigned i, j;
    double v;
    inputStream >> i >> j >> v;

   //check current size of the matrix and make it grow if necessary
   if ( (i >= mat.rows()) || (j >= mat.cols()) )
      mat.conservativeResize(std::max(i+1, mat.rows()), std::max(j+1, mat.cols()) );

   //store the value in matrix
   mat.coeffRef(i,j) = v;

   //Insert here your condition to break before of read all the stream
   if (mat.nonZeros() > 150 )
      break;
}

//Do some clean-up in case you think is necessary
mat.makeCompressed();
```

Comment: Ah, the leaving matrix entries untouched was important for conservativeResize, which I did not see. I had thought it destroyed the original data. Great.

Comment: You could also use `mat.reserve()` to pre-allocate some storage space for some number of anticipated nonzero entries. This works in a similar way to `std::vector::reserve`, which is also useful for building a sparse matrix in triplet form.